# Version one API - get sprint (timebox) wise counts of issues, stories, defects, backlog items

Tags: api, rest, versionone

My goal is to fetch just the counts of stories, issues, backlogs, defects associated with respect to a particular timebox and project.

I know I can fetch an asset's details using using this (for defects)

```
<Server Base URI>/rest-1.v1/Defect/?sel=Number,Name,CreateDate&where=Timebox.Name=<sprint name>;Scope.Name=<project>
```

But doing it this way I'd have to do query for different assets. Is it possible to get this sprint wise info with a single query.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.

Using [query.v1](https://versionone.github.io/api-docs/#queryv1) read-only API, I could achieve writing multiple queries. Also this repository here [grammars](https://github.com/versionone/Grammars), contains documentation of the syntax for tokens which can used within queries

```json
{
   "from":"Timebox",
   "where":{
      "Schedule.ScheduledScopes":"<SCOPE_ID>"
   },
   "select":[
      "Name",
      "BeginDate",
      "EndDate",
      "Workitems:<ASSET_TYPE>[AssetState!='Closed';Scope='<SCOPE_ID>'].@Count"
      ...
   ]
}
```

Replace SCOPE_ID (Project), ASSET_TYPE (Defect, Story etc.) to get the values